How to test time-to-intercative metric by using WebDriver Sampler?
I use WebDriver Sampler. And I have one successful result (screenshot). But I don't understand the "load time". Is it DOM tree loading or time-to-interactive loading or full page loading?
I need to take web performance one page and two metrics - time-to-interactive and full page loading. Is it real by using WebDriver Sampler and Jmeter?



The closest metric you can get easily would be querying domInteractive property value, something like:
def domInteractive = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.performance.timing.domInteractive")

For better results you might want to use tti-polyfill
If you use Chrome you can go for CDP and get TTI metric from there
More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
